# jQuery: loop through tbody elements and return div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many tbody elemnts like the one bellow, I try to loop through the tbody elements, then I look for the two div elements in order to give them the largest height of them:

```
<tbody class="form-row">
  <tr class="grp-tr djn-tr form-row has_original">

    <td style="" class="original">
      <p>
      </p>
    </td>

    <td class="grp-td djn-td">

      <div class="grp-readonly">
      </div>

    </td>

    <td class="grp-td djn-td">

      <div class="grp-readonly">
      </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

why the function bellow does not find div elements?? and how can I get the two div elements?

```
function myfunction() {
  var elements = $(".form-row");
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length - 2; i++) {
    alert(elements[i].nodeName); // works well, it shows TBODY
    var divs = $(elements[i].find("div.grp-readonly")); // Not working
    // some code here
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: As you're using jQuery, why not just `$('.form-row div').each()`?

Comment: use correct syntax ..var divs = $(elements[i]).find("div.grp-readonly");

Comment: ooh yes, stupid mistake. Thank you @shut

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I will try your proposal, it seems very simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(elements[i].find("div.grp-readonly"));` is incorrect, because you must move `.find` outside of element elector (in other words messing up code).

Try using `$.each` for simplicity:

```js
function myfunction() {  
  $(".form-row").each(function () {
    var div = $(this).find('.grp-readonly');
    
    console.log(div);
  });
}

myfunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody class="form-row">
    <tr class="grp-tr djn-tr form-row has_original">

      <td style="" class="original">
        <p>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td class="grp-td djn-td">

        <div class="grp-readonly">
        </div>

      </td>

      <td class="grp-td djn-td">

        <div class="grp-readonly">
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```